# Auto Fit tables to Columns Width without changing the font size

Tags: tables, two-column, fit

I am really tired of searching. It is very simple issue in MS-Word but how I can't run it in Latex.
I have a two column document. If a table has a enough width there is no problem, but if it was smaller than column width (Whether one or two column) I use `{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}` but it change the size of the font.
For example for the following code:

```
\section{RESULTS}\label{sec:res}One hundred patients enrolled in this study including 63 (63\%) men and 37 (37\%) women. Mean age of participants was 60 ± 5 years with minimum age of 44 years old and maximum age of 80 years old. Patients’ demographics are summarized in Table 1.\begin{table}[ht]\centering\caption{Patient Characteristics}\label{table1}\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.5\textwidth}\begin{tabular}{lc}\hlineCharacteristics                  & N = 100  \\\hlineAge (years)                      & 60 ± 5  \\Female                           & 37 (37) \\Diabetes mellitus                & 36 (36) \\Hypertension                     & 50 (50) \\hyperlipidemia                   & 50 (50) \\Smoker                           & 33 (33) \\Left ventricular function        &           \\\hspace{3mm}EF \textgreater= 45\%            & 84 (84) \\\hspace{3mm}30\% \textless EF \textless 45\% & 16 (16) \\\hspace{3mm}EF \textless= 30\%               & 0 (0) \\\hline\end{tabular}\end{adjustbox}\end{table}The minimum and maximum of measured peak SBP before CR, was 90 and 155 mmHg respectively. The mean of peak SBP was 121.95 ± 14.21 mmHg. The minimum and maximum of measured SBP after CR, was 100 mmHg and 150 mmHg respectively with mean of 121.55 ± 11.84 mmHg. Mean of SBP did not significantly change after CR (P = 0.76). The minimum of measured DBP before CR was 60 mmHg and the maximum was 90 mmHg with mean of 78.55 ± 7.18 mmHg. The minimum of measured DBP after CR was 60 mmHg and maximum was 90 mmHg. The mean DBP was 77.35 ± 7.08 mmHg. Mean of DBP was not significantly different before and after CR (P = 0.12) Minimum of PPI before CR was 0.33 and maximum of it was 0.83 with mean of 0.35 ± 0.046. After CR, minimum of PPI was 0.27 and maximum was 0.53 with mean of 0.36 ± 0.048. Mean of PPI was not significantly different before and after CR (P = 0.12).\\
```

Then I have:

[image: Why the size of the table is diffrent]

I used `{width=0.5\textwidth}` and if I changed the 0.5 to 1 the table turn even bigger.
Could anybody tell me that how can I only fit the tables to the columns width?

Thank you in advance for your supports.

Comment: `\columnwidth` is the length you want not `0.5\textwidth` but why do you want to scale the table at all, as your image shows it just makes it use an inconsistent font size, I would remove the `adjustbox` and let the existing `\centering` take effect.

Comment: Or do you want the effect of `tabularx`?

Answer (score 1):

By using `\adjustbox`, you basically guarantee some kind of major font size change. Use a `tabular*` environment instead.

Oh, and for well-spaced horizontal lines, do load the `booktabs` package and its macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros
\begin{document}

\section{Results}\label{sec:res}

One hundred patients enrolled in this study including 63 (63\%) men and 37 
(37\%) women. Mean age of participants was $60 \pm 5$ years with minimum 
age of 44 years old and maximum age of 80 years old. Patients' demographics 
are summarized in Table~\ref{table1}.

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Patient Characteristics}\label{table1}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lr@{}}
\toprule
Characteristics                  & $N = 100$  \\
\midrule
Age (years)                      & $60 \pm 5$  \\
Female                           & 37 (37) \\
Diabetes mellitus                & 36 (36) \\
Hypertension                     & 50 (50) \\
hyperlipidemia                   & 50 (50) \\
Smoker                           & 33 (33) \\
Left ventricular function        &  \\
\hspace{3mm}EF $\ge$ 45\%        & 84 (84) \\
\hspace{3mm}30\% $<$ EF $<$ 45\% & 16 (16) \\
\hspace{3mm}EF $\le$ 30\%        & 0 (0) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

The minimum and maximum of measured peak SBP before CR, was 90 and 
155 mmHg respectively. The mean of peak SBP was $121.95 \pm 14.21$ 
mmHg. The minimum and maximum of measured SBP after CR, was 100 mmHg 
and 150 mmHg respectively with mean of $121.55 \pm 11.84$ mmHg. Mean 
of SBP did not significantly change after CR ($P = 0.76$). The 
minimum of measured DBP before CR was 60 mmHg and the maximum was 
90 mmHg with mean of $78.55 \pm 7.18$ mmHg. The minimum of measured DBP 
after CR was 60 mmHg and maximum was 90 mmHg. The mean DBP was $77.35 
\pm 7.08$ mmHg. Mean of DBP was not significantly different before and 
after CR (P = 0.12) Minimum of PPI before CR was 0.33 and maximum of it 
was 0.83 with mean of $0.35 \pm 0.046$. After CR, minimum of PPI was 
0.27 and maximum was 0.53 with mean of $0.36 \pm 0.048$. Mean of PPI 
was not significantly different before and after CR ($P = 0.12$).

\end{document}
```